# php, foreach in foreach

Tags: php, foreach

In this code, there are two foreachs. It worked fine when I use it separately. However, it doesn't work together. I've been struggling with this problem for two days..

```
$urls = nl2br($this->input->post('urls'));
$result = explode("<br />", $urls);

$n = 0;
foreach($result as $row)
{
$n++;   
    $Google_Play_URL = $row;
    $string = file_get_contents($Google_Play_URL);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($string);
    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($anchors as $anchor) 
    {
    $i++;

        if ($anchor->nodeValue === 'Email Developer') {
            $email = str_replace('mailto:', '', $anchor->getAttribute('href'));

            if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                echo $email;

                $id = $this->session->userdata(SESSION_USERID); 

                $country = 'US';
                $type = 'android';

                $query = 'SELECT idx FROM db_advertisers WHERE email = "'.$email.'"';
                $result = $this->db->query($query);

                if($result->num_rows() < 1)
                {
                    $query = 'INSERT INTO db_advertisers (email, type, url, country, submit_user) VALUES ("'.$email.'", "'.$type.'", "'.$Google_Play_URL.'", "'.$country.'", "'.$id.'")';
                    $this->db->query($query);   
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

When I send multiple values, this code only save one data. It supposes to save multiple data. Can you see the problem?

Comment: You're resetting $result inside the loop, by using it for a new query result

Comment: @MarkBaker I've changed it $result->$result_data, but it still saving only first data.

Answer (score 5):

The only obvious issue is that in the inner foreach loop, you are setting

```
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

which is the same variable you have in the outer foreach loop

```
foreach($result as $row)
```

Changing one of the variable names should fix the issue.

Comment: it still saving only one data.